# Passing password in encrypted form to CSOM model

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

I want to send the password in encrypted form when creating a new `ClientContext` object. Is it possible and how?

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://yourserver/")) {
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the password as a [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx) to the [NetworkCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783904(v=vs.110).aspx).